# In symfony, what is a bag?

Tags: php, oop, symfony

I've found a decent answer regarding what is a bag in the context of java: [What is meant by the term "bag"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028838/what-is-meant-by-the-term-bag)

I did a google search and found that Symfony provides a lot of different "bag" interfaces like this one:

http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.html

In symfony, is the term bag meant to be interpreted as the same way? Also, how is this different from a "container" or "collection".

Comment: "ParameterBag is a container for key/value pairs."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A *bag* (the object's name is `ParameterBag`) contains variables or parameters.

A *collection* contains a list of elements (think of it as an oriented-object version of `array` with a lot of useful methods to manipulate the values). The object comes from [the Doctrine framework](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html). Symfony also has a concept of Collection and it is explained [in its documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Collection.html).

A [Container](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php#L23) contains all kind of objects, it has [its own ParameterBag object](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php#L18) with its parameters loaded from anything within the `parameters` key of your config file.

A [Request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L16) object (`$this->container->get('request')`) also has [its own ParameterBag](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php#L14).

Code-wise, the Container's parameter bag and the Request's parameter bag are different and could have different methods but their goals are identical.

Answer (score 1):

A `bag` is short for `ParameterBag`. A bag is a datatype used to help store data, similar to a collection in java. A bag specifically can access values via key/value as Dagon pointed out, but also has other operations that are useful.

The public operations of a bag are: `clear`, `add`, `all`, `get`, `set`, `has`, `remove`, `resolve`, `resolveValue`, `resolveString`, `isResolved`, `escapeValue`, and `unescapedValue`.

If you'd like to see the operations of a bag in detail, you can do so here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php